# How to know which mouse has generated MouseEvent that is received by my application?

Tags: .net, winapi, visual-c++, wdk

I have two mouse devices attached with my PC. So I want to detect which mouse has generated actual mouse event that is received in my application. You can simply think your laptop having track pad and usb mouse. I want to differentiate mouse event generated hardware.

I want this information in .Net Application. But I can use P/Invoke if Native Windows APIs are available. I am also interested with other solutions like Windows Mouse Hooks. But I don't know whether it works or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To distinguish events from different mice you can use use [Raw Input](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645543%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  I don't think this has a .Net interface, so you would have to use P/Invoke.

The [MultiPoint Mouse SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee906605.aspx) claims to make it simple to use multiple mice on a single PC.  I've never tried it, but it does have a .Net interface.